# How to Remove duplicates from javascript array having one unique identifier

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

I have an array like

```js
let arr = 
  [ { id: 1, name: 'a', age: 10 } 
  , { id: 2, name: 'a', age: 10 } 
  , { id: 3, name: 'b', age: 11 } 
  ]
```

I want to remove duplicate objects I  am looking for an optimize solution.
solution should be generic and should not be bound with object properties name except "id" property.
I mean it should work for below array also  ..

```js
    [
     {id:1, emp_name:'x', sal:33},
     {id:2, emp_name:'x', sal:33},
     {id:3, emp_name:'z', sal:35}
    ]
```

I am expecting

```js
  [ { id: 1, name: 'a', age: 10 } 
  , { id: 3, name: 'b', age: 11 } 
  ]
```

or

```js
    [
     {id:1, emp_name:'x', sal:33},
     {id:3, emp_name:'z', sal:35}
    ]
```

Comment: In the case of duplicates, who wins? First or last occurrence? ... a last-wins could be as concise as `[...new Map(arr.map((v) => [v.name, v])).values()]`

Comment: @spender your code  doesn't **remove** anything...

Comment: Item one and two have the same name and the same age, which key should be being used to determine the duplicate (or should it be both)?

Comment: Also do you actually care whether the item is removed from the original array or you get back a new array without duplicates?

Comment: @MisterJojo That's true. I tend to stay away from mutation :)

Comment: @spender yet your answer shows that you have produced a semantic mutation on the nature of the question...

Comment: the result array  should be  new one , no mutation.

Comment: You're supposed to ask your question all at once, not change issues over time. And by this way : are you aware that in all current cases the objects of these arrays remain the same?  should they also be duplicated?

Comment: sure , Jojo, all other classes would be different except one property which is id.thank you for the ans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to REMOVE an array element use `Array.splice()` method

```js
let arr = 
  [ { id: 1, name: 'a', age: 10 } 
  , { id: 2, name: 'a', age: 10 } 
  , { id: 3, name: 'b', age: 11 } 
  ];

for(let i=arr.length;--i>0;) // need to progress backward
  {
  if (i > arr.findIndex(e=>e.name===arr[i].name && e.age===arr[i].age))
    arr.splice(i,1);
  }

console.log(arr)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
.as-console-row::after {display: none !important;}
```

**Generic solution**

```js
const
  arr1 = 
    [ { id: 1, name: 'a', age: 10 } 
    , { id: 2, name: 'a', age: 10 } 
    , { id: 3, name: 'b', age: 11 } 
    ]
, arr2 = 
    [ { id:1, emp_name:'x', sal:33 }
    , { id:2, emp_name:'x', sal:33 }
    , { id:3, emp_name:'z', sal:35 }
    ];

removeDuplicates(arr1);
console.log('arr1-->', arr1);
 
removeDuplicates(arr2);
console.log('arr2-->', arr2);
 

function removeDuplicates(arr)
  {
  let keys = Object.keys(arr[0]).reduce((kn,k)=>((k==='id')?null:kn.push(k),kn),[]);
      // get key names (except 'id')
 
  for(let i=arr.length;--i>0;) // need to progress backward
    {
    if (i >  arr.findIndex(e=>keys.reduce((b,k)=> b && e[k]===arr[i][k] ,true))) 
      arr.splice(i,1);
    }
  }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
.as-console-row::after {display: none !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

```js
const res = arr.reduce(
    (acc, x) =>
        !acc.has(Object.values(x).slice(1).join(''))
            ? acc.set(Object.values(x).slice(1).join(''), x)
            : acc,
    new Map()
)
console.log(Array.from(res.values()))
```

Or if you don't want to make new arrays, maps and so on:

```js
for (let i = 0, remove = false; i < arr.length; !remove && i++) {
    remove =
        arr.findIndex(
            (t, ti) =>
                ti < i &&
                Object.values(arr[i]).every(
                    (x, j) => j === 0 || x === Object.values(t)[j]
                )
        ) + 1
    if (remove) arr.splice(i, 1)
}
```

You can loop through array backwards as well so you don't need to fix the index increment or the length of loop.

```js
for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    let duplicateIdx = arr.findIndex(t =>
        Object.values(arr[i]).every((x, j) => j === 0 || x === Object.values(t)[j])
    )
    if (duplicateIdx !== -1 && duplicateIdx < i) arr.splice(i, 1)
}
```

Also if your id property may not be the 1st key:

```js
for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    let duplicateIdx = arr.findIndex(t =>
        Object.keys(arr[i]).every(key => key === 'id' || arr[i][key] === t[key])
    )
    if (duplicateIdx !== -1 && duplicateIdx < i) arr.splice(i, 1)
}
```

Comment: Thank you but .. I missed one thing to mention !! solution should not be property bound (except id ), I have updated the description , and also added one solution. but still looking for better one :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have created below but I am looking for more optimized one ..

```js
for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
  {
    for(let j=i+1;j<arr.length;j++)
      { 
        let o1 =  {...arr[i]};
        let o2 =  {...arr[j]};       
        delete o1.id ;delete o2.id ;                
        if(JSON.stringify(o1) === JSON.stringify(o2))
        {          
          arr.splice(i,1);          
        }
      }
  }

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```